# Ancestor/parent item key in Sitecore

Tags: xslt, sitecore

Wondering whether you could help me out with this one.

I am looping through items in Sitecore and showing a carousel of all the categories in `$products/item` with the template being `productcategory`.

I would like to add a class which highlights the **current** item's category but cannot work out how to get the ancestor item's `keyvalueofparent`.

Here is my code segment in question:

```
<ul>

  <xsl:for-each select="$products/item[@template='productcategory']">

    <li>

      <xsl:attribute name="class">cat cat<xsl:value-of select="position()" />

        <xsl:if test="./@key = 'keyvalueofparent'">active</xsl:if>

      </xsl:attribute>
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: try `<xsl:if test="../@key = 'keyvalueofparent'">active</xsl:if>`

Comment: sorry, `./@key` is fine, i am looking for `keyvalueofparent`

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen - your comment pointed it me to the right path after all, thanks.

Comment: I highly recommend not using XSLT.  Life will be much less frustrating.

Comment: I know @BenGolden. As I said in my question, I'm stuck supporting an application that uses it heavily. Not much I can do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else has trouble with this. As with most things, the problem lies within the logic.

No matter what I tried instead of `'keyvalueofparent'` I would always be stuck within the context of `$products/item[@template='productcategory']`.

So, to get around that, all I needed to do is declare a variable outside of that context, that way it will refer to the parent of the current item:

```
<xsl:variable name="parentkey" select="../@key" />
```

And then proceed to use the variable within the loop:

```
<ul>
  <xsl:for-each select="$products/item[@template='productcategory']">

    <li>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        cat cat<xsl:value-of select="position()" />
        <xsl:if test="./@key = $parentkey">
          active
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:attribute>
```